# GDB - Assembly program returns /bin/sh: 0: Can't open �

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, x86-64, shellcode

I am presently learning 64-bit assembly language from the related Pentester Academy course. The code I'm working on creates the following error when ran in GDB:

> /bin/sh: 0: Can't open �
>   [Inferior 1 (process 4049) exited with code 0177]

I have googled the error and exit code and haven't found anything helpful. I tried analyzing the code in GDB over and over, but all the right values seem to be in the right registers. I can't seem to find what's wrong.

You can find the code below. My goal is simply to invoke the execve syscall using the jump-call-pop technique.

```
global _start
section .text

_start:

jmp bash

code:

xor rax, rax
pop rdi
mov [rdi +7], al    

push rdi
mov rsi, rsp
push rax
mov rdx, rsp
mov al, 59
syscall 

bash:

call code 
string:     db      '/bin/shABBBBBBBBCCCCCCCC'
```

EDIT:

Here is how I built the program:

```
nasm -f elf64 -o execve_stack_jcp.o execve_stack_jcp.asm 
ld -o execve_stack_jcp execve_stack_jcp.o
```

I then use `objdump -M intel -d execve_stack_jcp` to output the disassembly which I then input in this c program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned char code[] = \
"\xeb\x13\x48\x31\xc0\x5f\x88\x47\x07\x57\x48\x89\xe6\x50\x48\x89\xe2\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05\xe8\xe8\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x41\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x42\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43\x43";

int main(void) {

printf("Shellcode length: %d\n", (int)strlen(code));

int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;

ret();

return 0;
}
```

Finally, I compile the c program using:

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o shellcode shellcode.c
```

Comment: How did you build this code?

Comment: Of course JMP/CALL/POP method isn't required in 64-bit code if you use RiP (relative) addressing.

Comment: Would help if you showed how you build and execute your program. But one observation is that with `execve` `argv` and `argp` need to be NULL terminated lists of strings but you only null terminate argp (by pushing `rax` first). You need to NULL terminate `argv` too. So **before** `push rdi` you should also do `push rax`

Comment: I see you updated your question. did you see the comment I made about null terminating the string array `argv`  ?

Comment: Hello @MichaelPetch, thanks for the answer! Can't understand how I missed that. As a side note, I am aware of the RIP relative addressing technique, this program was simply used to understand how jump-call-pop works ;-)

Comment: Hey @MichaelPetch, it's my first time on Stack Overflow, so please excuse my ignorance. Is there a way to upvote your comment so that it appears as the answer that worked for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[execve](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) in Linux is defined this way:

> int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[],
> char *const envp[]);
>
> [snip]
>
> argv is an array of argument strings passed to the new program.  By  convention, the first of these strings (i.e., argv[0]) should contain the filename associated with the file being executed.  envp is an array of strings, conventionally of the form key=value, which are passed as environment to the new program.  The **argv** and **envp arrays** must each include a **null pointer** at the **end of the array**.

If you were to run your program through `strace ./shellcode` you'd probably see something *similar* to this:

> execve("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh", "\270", "\1", "\353\23H1\300_\210G\7WH\211\346PH\211\342\260;\17\5\350\350\377\377\377/bin/s"...], [/* 0 vars */]) = 0

You'll notice the second argument `argv` has a bunch of extra entries in the array. This is because you didn't *NULL* terminate the `argv` array. To correct this you could modify your code by pushing 0 (via *RAX*) onto the stack like this:

```
xor rax, rax 
pop rdi
mov [rdi +7], al

push rax      ; NULL terminates the `argv` array
push rdi
mov rsi, rsp
push rax
mov rdx, rsp
```

If you were to run this change through `strace` again you'd see something like:

> execve("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh"], [/* 0 vars */]) = 0

This should end up being a successful `execve` call.